# Segmentation Faultエラーの要因について

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

今研究で[TEPLA](http://www.cipher.risk.tsukuba.ac.jp/tepla/index.html)というオープンソースライブラリを利用して楕円曲線暗号を利用した署名の作成や検証を行うプログラムを書いています。
度々Segmentation Faultエラーが出るのですが、今回はソースコードの`//Segmentation Fault`の部分でSegmentation Faultまたはエラーや警告なしで終了するのですが、その要因になっていそうなどの変数(calcpair, content.aggsig, g, ptmp)についても予期していない挙動は行っておりません。
解決法やご指摘、意見など聞かせていただけると幸いです。よろしくおねがいします。

gdbを利用してデバッグした結果、該当の行での外部ライブラリ参照の際にGMPの関数?(`__gmpn_copyi`)を呼び出しているようなのですが、そこでSegmentation faultを起こしているようです。
aggregate.cを修正しました。ですが、エラーはそのままでした。

aggregate.c

```
#include"integrated.h"

void aggregate(int auth)
{
extern mdata *mod;
extern cdata content;
extern EC_POINT g;
extern EC_PAIRING p;
extern EC_POINT publickey;

int i, j;
int mnmb;
unsigned char aggstr[65536] = { 0 };
unsigned char pair[1024] = { 0 };
unsigned char strbuff[1024] = { 0 };
unsigned char gbuf[512] = { 0 };
FILE *aggregatefile;
FILE *pairing1st;
FILE *pairing2nd;
FILE *pkey;
Element calcpair;
Element pairbuff;
Element verify;

//Evacuate parameter g
point_get_str(gbuf, g);

//Initialize
mnmb = content.nummodel;
pairing_clear(p);
pairing_init(p, "ECBN254a");
point_init(g, p->g1);
point_set_str(g, gbuf);
point_init(content.aggsig, p->g2);
point_set_infinity(content.aggsig);
point_init(publickey, p->g1);
element_init(calcpair, p->g3);
element_set_one(calcpair);
element_init(pairbuff, p->g3);
element_set_one(pairbuff);
element_init(verify, p->g3);

for (i = 0; i < mnmb; i++)
{
    point_init(mod[i].signature, p->g2);
    point_set_str(mod[i].signature, mod[i].sigstr);
    point_init(mod[i].hash, p->g2);
    point_set_str(mod[i].hash, mod[i].hashstr);
}

if (auth == 1)
{
    aggregatefile = fopen("slot/aggregate_sig.txt", "w");
    pairing1st = fopen("slot/pairing1st.txt", "w");
}
else {
    aggregatefile = fopen("slot'/aggregate_sig.txt", "w");
    pairing1st = fopen("slot/pairing1st.txt", "r");
    pairing2nd = fopen("slot'/pairing2nd.txt", "w");
    pkey = fopen("slot/publickey.txt", "r");

    if (pairing1st == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (pkey == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to open file.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

printf("Try to make aggregate signature.\n");
for (i = 0; i < mnmb; i++)
{
    point_add(content.aggsig, content.aggsig, mod[i].signature);
}

point_get_str(aggstr, content.aggsig);
fputs(aggstr, aggregatefile);
printf("Make aggregate signature!\nSave to aggregate_sig.txt\n\n");

printf("g->");
point_print(g);
printf("\n");
printf("Aggregate signature->");
point_print(content.aggsig);
printf("\n\n");
//printf("Element->");
//element_print(calcpair);
//printf("\n");

printf("Calculate pairing.\n");
if (auth == 1)
{
    pairing_map(calcpair, content.aggsig, g, p);    //Segmentation fault
    element_get_str(pair, calcpair);
    fputs(pair, pairing1st);
}
else {
    fgets(strbuff, 1024, pkey);
    point_set_str(publickey, strbuff);
    fgets(strbuff, 1024, pairing1st);
    element_set_str(verify, strbuff);

    for (i = 0; i < mnmb; i++)
    {
        pairing_map(pairbuff, mod[i].hash, publickey, p);
        element_mul(calcpair, calcpair, pairbuff);
    }

    if (element_cmp(verify, calcpair) == 0)
    {
        printf("Signature is legal.\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Signature is illegal.\n");
    }
}

fclose(aggregatefile);
fclose(pairing1st);
fclose(pairing2nd);
fclose(pkey);

printf("aggregate.c Finished.\n\n");
}
```

integrated.h

```
#pragma once

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<time.h>
#include<tepla/ec.h>

//Path for various files
#define KEYPATH "slot/publickey.txt"
#define PMMDATA "share/sample.pmm"
#define SETTINGPATH "slot/control_settings.txt"

//model data structure
typedef struct modeldata {
int modelid;        //Model ID in content
char janame[32];    //Model's Japasese name
char enname[32];    //Model's English name
char filepath[256];     //File path to model data
int modify;         //Check flag for modification
int change;         //Check flag for changable
int delete;         //Check flag for deletable
int add;            //Check flag for addable
unsigned int permit;    //Permission for edit control
EC_POINT hash;      //Buffer for caliculating value of hash
char hashstr[1024];     //For saving hash data
EC_POINT signature;     //Buffer for caliculating signature
char sigstr[1024];      //For saving signature data
} mdata;

//content data structure
typedef struct contentdata {
int nummodel;
EC_POINT aggsig;
} cdata;

extern void Init_tepla();
extern void CLK_INIT();
extern void CLK_START();
extern void CLK_END();
```

main.c

```
#include"integrated.h"

//Define global variables
clock_t clk[2] = { 0,0 };
EC_PAIRING p;
EC_POINT g;
EC_POINT publickey;
gmp_randstate_t state;
mpz_t grx;
cdata content;
mdata *mod;

//Define external function
extern void keygen();
extern void dataextract();
extern void siggen(int auth);
extern void aggregate(int auth);
void Init_tepla();
void CLK_INIT();
void CLK_START();
void CLK_END();

//main
int main()
{   
unsigned int author = 0;

//input
scanf("%d", &author);

CLK_INIT();
CLK_START();
keygen();
dataextract();
siggen(author);
aggregate(author);

free(mod);

printf("Program finished.\n");
CLK_END();

return 0;
}

//To initialize tepla
void Init_tepla()
{
printf("Initialize tepla\n");
pairing_init(p, "ECBN254a");
point_init(g, p->g1);
point_random(g);

mpz_init(grx);
gmp_randinit_default(state);
gmp_randseed_ui(state, (unsigned)time(NULL));
mpz_urandomb(grx, state, 256);
}

//Functions to measure elapsed time
void CLK_INIT()
{
clk[0] = clock();
clk[1] = clock();
}

void CLK_START()
{
clk[0] = clock();
}

void CLK_END()
{
clk[1] = clock();
double elapsed_time = (double)(clk[1] - clk[0]) / (CLOCKS_PER_SEC)*1000;
printf("Elapsed time is %.2lf [ms]\n", elapsed_time);
}
```

Comment: pairing_mapという関数のところでセグメンテーションフォールトが起きるとの事ですが、pairing_mapのコードが示されていないので検討することは不可能です。「度々Segmentation Faultエラーが出るのですが、今回はソースコード」とありますので、「度々Segmentation Faultエラーが出る」ソースコードと、「今回の」ソースコードの両方を質問に追加すべきだと考えます。　どんなコードか判らないプログラムの不具合の原因を質問するのが非常識であることは理解できますか？

Comment: @Fumu7 曖昧な質問をしてしまい申し訳ありません。pairing_mapという関数はリンクにあるTEPLAというライブラリの関数で、「第2、第3引数の値を第4引数の楕円曲線を用いてペアリングを算出し、結果を第1引数に格納する」というものになっております。またこのソースコードだけでSegmentation faultが出てエラーになる場合と警告もなくプログラムが終了してしまう場合がある、という意味で書いたつもりでしたが言葉足らずでした。申し訳ありません。

Comment: 「警告もなくプログラムが終了してしまう場合」というのは、”printf("aggregate.c Finished.\n\n");”の行まで実行されるという事ですか？

Comment: @Fumu7 いえ、同じ場所でSegmentation fault が出ずにプログラムが終了するという意味です。

Comment: 前回と同様のファイル構成だとすれば、`integrated.h` と `main.c` も記載して貰えると原因を特定しやすくなるかと思います。また、写し間違いかもしれませんが、`aggsig = fopen("slot'/aggregate_sig.txt", "w");` となっていて、ディレクトリ名に `'`(アポストロフィ)が付いています(`pairing2nd` も同様)。

Comment: segmentation faltとのコメントがある行を過ぎれば、ifのブロックの実行を終えて、いくつかのファイルのクローズに続いて”printf("aggregate.c Finished.\n\n");”の行が実行されると思うのですが、最後のprintfは実行されないのですか？？

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます。該当のソースコードを記載しました。ファイルオープンについてはわざとそうしています....紛らわしくて申し訳ありません。

Comment: @Fumu7 最後のprintfは実行されていません。なお直後にprintfを置いても実行せずに終了したので、おそらくSegmentation faultのコメントがある行でプログラムが強制終了しています。

Comment: 問題の `pairing_map()` なのですが、第3引数の `g` が `point_init(g, p->g1);` で初期化されていて、第2引数の `content.aggsig` と同じになっています。TEPLA のサンプルコードを見ると、`p->g1` と `p->g2` で初期化した EC_POINT 型変数をペアリングしていて、試しに `point_init(g, p->g2);` してみると正常終了する様になりました(`./slot/pairing1st.txt` が生成されています)。ただ、`keygen()`, `dataextract()`, `siggen()` の定義が無いので、これが適切が対処なのかどうかは分かりません。

Comment: @metropolis ありがとうございます！！生成元の見直しは見落としていました！